# Parser works for some ArrayLists, throws Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING for others

Tags: java, json, gson

I had issues with this but read other questions on Stack Overflow and initially solved the problems. Now I can send JSON between my Client and Server and create objects from this JSON in the Client. However, I keep getting this error with one specific object:

```java
client.restaurant = gson.fromJson(obj.get("restaurant"), Restaurant.class); // works
client.postcodes = gson.fromJson(obj.get("postcodes"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Postcode>>(){}.getType()); // works
client.orders = gson.fromJson(obj.get("orders"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Order>>(){}.getType()); // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $[0].dishes.updateListeners
```

All the JSON is valid as per https://jsonlint.com. I have no idea how to find out more about this issue, but one thing I tried was I extracted the JSON for `ArrayList<Order> orders` and tried to parse it manually:

```java
JsonObject testOrder = parser.parse("{\n" + 
                        "    \"orders\": [\n" + 
                        "        {\n" + 
                        "            \"user\": {\n" + 
                        "                \"userName\": \"Admin\",\n" + 
                        "                \"password\": \"password\",\n" + 
                        "                \"address\": \"University Road\",\n" + 
                        "                \"postcode\": {\n" + 
                        "                    \"postcodeName\": \"SO17 1BJ\",\n" + 
                        "                    \"latLong\": {\n" + 
                        "                        \"lon\": 0.0,\n" + 
                        "                        \"lat\": 0.0\n" + 
                        "                    },\n" + 
                        "                    \"distance\": 0,\n" + 
                        "                    \"updateListeners\": []\n" + 
                        "                },\n" + 
                        "                \"updateListeners\": []\n" + 
                        "            },\n" + 
                        "            \"dishes\": {\n" + 
                        "                \"Sushi Roll\": 5,\n" + 
                        "                \"Side Rice\": 2\n" + 
                        "            },\n" + 
                        "            \"name\": \"07/05/2019 10:23:08\",\n" + 
                        "            \"updateListeners\": []\n" + 
                        "        }\n" + 
                        "    ]\n" + 
                        "}").getAsJsonObject();
client.orders = gson.fromJson(testOrder, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Order>>(){}.getType()));
```

but this also doesn't work (the error is subtly different -- `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`).

**Edit:**

Order.java

```java
package comp1206.sushi.common;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import comp1206.sushi.common.Order;

public class Order extends Model implements Serializable {

    private String status;
    private User user;
    private HashMap<Dish, Number> dishes = new HashMap<Dish, Number>();

    public Order() {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");  
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
        this.name = dtf.format(now);
    }

    public Order(User user) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");  
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
        this.name = dtf.format(now);
        setUser(user);
    }

    public Order(User user, Map<Dish, Number> basket) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");  
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
        this.name = dtf.format(now);
        setUser(user);
        basket.forEach((k,v)->addDishes(k,v));
    }

    public Number getDistance() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        notifyUpdate("status",this.status,status);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void addDishes(Dish dish, Number quantity) {
        // may need to call notifyUpdate?
        dishes.put(dish, quantity);
    }

    public void editDishes(Dish dish, Number quantity) {
        dishes.replace(dish, quantity);
    }

    public void clearDishes() {
        dishes.clear();
    }

    public Number getCost() {
        int total = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Dish, Number> entry : dishes.entrySet()) {
            int temptotal1 = (int) entry.getKey().getPrice();
            int temptotal2 = (int) entry.getValue();
            total += (temptotal1*temptotal2);
        }
        return total;
    }

    public Map<Dish, Number> getOrderContents() {
        return dishes;
    }

}
```

Postcode.java:

```java
package comp1206.sushi.common;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import comp1206.sushi.common.Postcode;

public class Postcode extends Model implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2179416792423154920L;

    private String postcodeName;
    private Map<String,Double> latLong;
    private Number distance;

    public Postcode(String code) {
        this.postcodeName = code;
        calculateLatLong();
        this.distance = Integer.valueOf(0);
    }

    public Postcode(String code, Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.postcodeName = code;
        calculateLatLong();
        calculateDistance(restaurant);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.postcodeName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.postcodeName = name;
    }

    public Number getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }

    public Map<String,Double> getLatLong() {
        return this.latLong;
    }

    protected void calculateDistance(Restaurant restaurant) {
        //This function needs implementing
        Postcode destination = restaurant.getLocation();
        this.distance = Integer.valueOf(0);
    }

    protected void calculateLatLong() {
        //This function needs implementing
        this.latLong = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        latLong.put("lat", 0d);
        latLong.put("lon", 0d);
        this.distance = new Integer(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of your objects and specifically Order ?

Comment: is the property for dishes really named "Sushi Roll" and "Side Rice" having spaces is property names is not recommended...

Comment: Also can you please tell us which Gson version you are using ?

Comment: @BorislavMarkov I have added Order and Postcode to the post, since an `ArrayList` of Postcodes works fine but an `ArrayList` of Orders doesn't. I'm using version `2.8.5` of Gson.

Comment: @Jocke yes, they do have spaces in the property names. I tried to load it in without the spaces, but I had the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Also can you please share the code of Dish, Model and User in order to reconstruct the project at my side.

Comment: @BorislavMarkov all requested classes are found in the following paste: https://ghostbin.com/paste/y7yxw
Let me know if you want anything else -- the overall project is very large and has many classes not yet sent (like the Client, Server, or the Communication classes). It will be difficult to send them all over.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I think your problem is around this:

```
"dishes": {  
    "Sushi Roll": 5,
    "Side Rice": 2
}
```

It tries to invoke method of Order `addDishes(Dish dish, Number quantity)` but it fails, because It has `"Sushi Roll"` instead of whole object which represents the `Dish`. You need to update Json instead of string to have object which match constructor of `Dish`. Something like:

```
"dishes": {  
    {"name":"Sushi Roll","description":"", "price":0.0, "restockThreshold": 0, "restockAmount":0}: 5,
    {"name":"Side Rice","description":"", "price":0.0, "restockThreshold": 0, "restockAmount":0}: 2
}
```

In general when dealing with Json you need to follow some rules.

- Always put default constructor with no arguments to data objects.
- Try to keep all collections with getter and setter.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that my issue is here... specifically because "dishes" is an ArrayList of other HashMaps, (so "Sushi Roll" and "Side Rice" are the keys and are themselves objects of type Ingredient, with 5 an 2 respectively being their associated value in the HashMap). I'm not sure how to fix this but thank you for finding what broke everything!